# Using MySQL how can I select a large group that must include a smaller group?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I want to select 5000 rows randomly from a Db of 48000 rows, but I want to make sure 30 rows (that I have unique ids for) are part of that select.  It there a way to do this in MySQL?

id, question, answer, category, etc...

Comment: yes .. show a sample fo data and the expeceted  result ... and the query you have tried to write ..

Comment: So, basically, you want to select your desired 30 rows and then also select 4970 random rows?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the records you have ids for first into a placeholder array, then select the balance using RAND().

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (list_of_ids)// put this in array...

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (list_of_ids) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4970// put this in second array...

$myResults = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

The performance should be fine for a table the size you describe...

As stated by Bill you could do this in one query with UNION...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (list_of_ids)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (list_of_ids) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4970
```